# laravel Динамическая реализация интерфейса

Tags: интерфейс, laravel-5.8, реализация

Имеется интерфейс SMSService , его реализует класс MegafonSMS
Регистрация реализатора интерфейса происходит через сервис-провайдер

```
$this->app->singleton(SMSService::class, function ($app) {
        return MegafonSMS::getInstance();
    });
```

Как понятно из название - класс для работы\отправки смс через Мегафон.
Возникла необходимость добавить еще 1 реализатор интерфейса - условный MtsSMS.
Передо мной стоит задача в зависимости от передаваемого\получаемого номера выбирать нужный класс реализатор интерфейса.
Но при текущей реализации - выбор класса-реализатора происходит до того, как будут получены данные(номер телефона).

**Вопрос** - как в данном случае лучше реализовать задачу? Я смотрю в сторону фасадов\контрактов.

Пример вызова функционала:

```
$smsStatus = $this->smsService->messageSend($phone, $userMessage);
```

И мне хотелось бы сохранить похожий принцип работы. Т.е. обращение к smsService и уже он подтягивает нужный обработчик.

Как я вижу текущий вариант реализации задачи - я пишу класс smsService 
Происходит вызов

```
smsService->messageSend($phone, $userMessage)
```

в самом классе такой код

```
    ...
public function checkPhone($phone) {
//код для обработки телефона и выбора оператора
return 'name';
}

public function messageSend($phone, $userMessage) {
$name = checkPhone($phone);
return $name->messageSend($phone, $userMessage);
}
```

Соответственно вместо $name будет MegafonSMS , MtsSMS или любой другой нужный класс в будущем.